# Группировка категории по дате и количеству

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Как реализовать группировку конкретной категории по дате и количеству и как это можно все автоматизировать?

На *рис1* показана исходная таблица. Нужно по выбранной категории скомплектовать по дате и количеству (результат на *рис2*). То есть сколько товара данной категории было продано за 1 и последующие дни. 
Использую для группировки:

```
group_goods_by_date = source.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'), 'category'])
group_goods_by_date=source[(source['DateTime'] < '2016-09-02') & (source['category'] == 0)]
```

Не работает должным образом, должна получиться таблица. И как можно автоматизировать, чтобы каждый раз не обращаться к номеру категории?

[image: рис1]

[image: рис2]

```
Date        Quantity    Category
2016-09-01    1     0
2016-09-01    1     0
2016-09-01    1     1
2016-09-01    1     2
2016-09-02    1     1
2016-09-03    1     0
```

Должно получиться по категории 0:

```
Date        Quantity    
2016-09-01    2     
2016-09-03    1
```

Comment: `source.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='DateTime', freq='D'), 'category'])['amount'].sum()` ?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Не совсем то, что нужно. Таким образом мне выделяет все категории товара за этот день, а мне нужен только один конкретный.

Comment: Вы можете привести пример данных в виде текста и желательно воспроизводимый (т.е. с датами вместо чисел и с вашими реальными именами столбцов) - это позволит использовать эти данные для создания DataFrame. Набирать данные с картинки - лень...

Comment: Внес изменения в исходный вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно создать словарь DataFrame'ов:

```
In [82]: df_dict = {k:v.reset_index(name='Quantity')
    ...:            for k,v in df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D', key='Date'),
    ...:                                   'Category'])['Quantity'].sum()
    ...:                         .groupby(level=1)}

In [83]: df_dict.keys()
Out[83]: dict_keys([0, 1, 2])

In [84]: df_dict[0]
Out[84]:
        Date  Category  Quantity
0 2016-09-01         0         2
1 2016-09-03         0         1

In [85]: df_dict[1]
Out[85]:
        Date  Category  Quantity
0 2016-09-01         1         1
1 2016-09-02         1         1

In [86]: df_dict[2]
Out[86]:
        Date  Category  Quantity
0 2016-09-01         2         1
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!